# How can I apply a particular file from a Git patch file?

Tags: git

I have a Git patch consisting 6 files.

1. abc.php
2. pqr.php
3. zyz.php
4. rrr.php
5. ggg.php
6. yyy.php

I want to apply only rrr.php from the `.patch` file consisting the above files

`git-apply` command includes an `--exclude` arg, but not `--include`.

How can I apply only rrr.php from the `.patch` file?

Answer (score 25):

You say:

> `git-apply` command includes an `--exclude` arg, but not `--include`

The [`git-apply`(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-apply.html) says:

> `--include=<path-pattern>`
>
> Apply changes to files matching the given path pattern. This can be useful when importing patchsets, where you want to include certain files or directories.

Try:

```
git apply --include=rrr.php some.patch
```

Verified with Git version 1.8.4.